# Work around to achieve user pool migration with current setting: "CUSTOM_AUTH"

Tags: amazon-cognito

Currently using "CUSTOM_AUTH" as the authenticationFlowType in Amplify config for email based MFA. I'm trying to operate User Pool Migration using "User Migration Trigger". But the conflict is that to do that "User Migration Trigger" requires "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH" according to the document, and tested that the "User Migration Trigger" only gets triggered with "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH". As I'm looking for work-around to do this, does any one have suggestion here?

I tried using CUSTOM_AUTH flow, but never worked.

Expectation:

- Keeping CUSTOM_AUTH flow and still be able to operate the user pool migration.
- After the migration, user don't need to change their password.